# Что есть вещь?

Tags: значение-слов

Задумалась: а что, собственно, есть "вещь"? С одной стороны, - это неодушевленный предмет, но можно ли тогда назвать вещью, скажем, дом? Или вещь - это только то, что можно взять в руки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ВЕЩЬ-слово многозначное. По Ожегову:  1. Отдельный предмет, изделие. Антикварная в.

2.То, что принадлежит к личному движимому имуществу. Сдать вещи в багаж.

3.О произведении науки, искусства. Удачная в. Слабая в.

4.Нечто,обстоятельство, явление. Произошла непонятная в. Прекрасная в. - молодость! Называть вещи своими именами (говорить прямо, не скрывая истины).

II уменьш.вещица, -ы, ас. (к 1 и 3 знач.; о чем-н. хорошем) и вещичка, -и, ас. (к 1, 2и 3 знач.). II прил. вещный, -ая, -ое (к 1 и 2 знач.; спец.) и вещевой, -ая,-ое (ко 2 знач.).  Вещное право (имущественное право владения вещами). Вещная болезнь (пристрастие к приобретению вещей во 2 знач., вещизм). Вещевой мешок.

http://slovarozhegova.ru/word.php?wordid=2999

Но вот чтобы про дом сказать"вещь" - вряд ли, это уже имущество -недвижимость, а есть движимое имущество - машина, яхта. Вещь, скорее, небольшой или средний предмет, чтобы можно было взять в руки.

Answer (score 2):

*Вещь* происходит от *вещать* (вещий Олег - святой, мудрый), то есть когда-то для создания предмета нужно было всего лишь создать и озвучить мыслеформу. Вот о какой древности хранит память наш язык.
Кстати, по-украински *вещь* будет "речь". *Речи напрокат*))))

Answer (score 1):

Вещь не происходит от слова "вещать". Вещь - это "названное".

В и.-е. языке отмечаются два разных корня, в дальнейшем связанные (но не межу собой, а со следующими предметами): (1) со знанием/мудростью и (2) с голосом/речью: veid (видеть, замечать, ведать) и  vek (говорить). Сравнить: vox (лат.) - голос, wit (англ.) - ум.

Слово "вещь" в др.-рус. языке известно с 11 века, как и слово вещий/мудрый, причем в форме 
вѣщий.

Comment: Уважаемый П.Я́. Черны́х (1896 - 1970), доктор филологических наук, профессор Московского государственного университета, автор "Историко-этимологического словаря современного русского языка" получил два минусовых очка, так как сведения о происхождении слова "вещь" взяты из его словарной статьи.

Comment: Никакого противоречия. "Названное" - и таким образом "созданное". (если "два разных корня" связаны "в дальнейшем", почему исключается, что они были связаны прежде?)))) С украинскими "речами напрокат" как будем быть, мм?

 Формат не позволяет нырнуть в философские глубины, но "В начале было Слово" известно каждому. Именно словом всё и творилось.

Comment: И кстати, латинское res есть ни что иное, как наша "речь". Однако переводится как "дело". Res publika - "общественное дело".
 "Ржеч Посполита" сюда же.